# child div not expanding with content

Tags: css, layout, html

I already looked at a few answers here in stackoverflow without success, so let me post my link here:

http://www.copycopy.it/index.php?go=how

On this page for example, the white div (#body_content_container) should expand with the content, but it doesn't. The same holds true for this page: http://www.copycopy.it/index.php?go=termsAndConditions

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here? I have tried `clear:both;` on the child divs, but no luck.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not clicking on a random link from an unknown website. Could you provide more details, or replicate the problem on a http://jsfiddle.com?

Comment: Where you are facing problem, Please put the code,then only others can help you

Comment: From the link you have access to the html and css, that's why I wanted to avoid posting code here... Nonetheless the answer from @kwon below has solved the matter... :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the height: 100%; from your elements. If you want it to expand to the length of the content, you don't want to specify a height. Besides, it'd only expand to the length of the window anyway.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove `height: 85%;` from `#content_text`.
2. Replace both `position:absolute;` and `position:relative;` with `float:left;`.
3. Replace any `top`, `left` or `padding` with a `margin`.

For example :

```
#columnHeader {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    width: 940px;
}

#column1 {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    text-align: justify;
    width: 285px;
}

#column2 {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 40px;
    text-align: justify;
    width: 275px;
}

#column3 {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
    text-align: justify;
    width: 320px;
}
```